# Microsoft Graph set unified group default notebook

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a scenario where I'm trying to provision a group and pre-populate the one note with template pages.
Doing posts to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupid>/onenote/notebooks` and subsequent endpoints I'm able to create everything.
However whenever the user goes to outlook, and clicks on the `OneNotes` button, it creates a brand new notebook which is empty.
The question is: **how can I set my notebook to be the default of the group?**
Thanks!
[image: button that redirects the user to the default notebook]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more investigation **the default notebook for the group is created automatically** after the group creation. There doesn't seem to be a way to change the default notebook at the moment.
The **creation of that notebook can take some time** (undocumented at the moment) which can range from a couple of milliseconds to minutes so **your code should plan for that** as well.
Finally, after being created, **the notebook can take additional time to appear in the UI** (like when adding a tab in Microsoft Teams)